# Delaying a tcp stream. I.e. Copy from a socket to another with 10sec delay

Tags: python, c, tcp, buffering

I need to synchronize two different streams of data. I'll call them strem A and B in the following. 
At time zero, both streams start from the sender. But stream A suffer a delay at the beginning of transmission (in the range 1s to 10sec) with respect to stream B.
At the receiver, I need to synchronize the streams, so what I need is a (python, C, C++, Java), program that open the socket to receive B (to a given IP:port) buffer the data for (example. 10sec), and then start to:
1) read the data from B and copy them in a queue.
2) read data from the front of the queue and send them to another ip:port.
In this way, in the latter port I can read them, synchronized with A.
I don't know if netcat, or other tools can do this with some options, or if there are already programs (under Windows 10) that can be used to do this.
Eventually I can write the code, but I really like to know some directions, for a solution. Thanks.

Comment: You might have better luck on SuperUser or ServerFault. See the last section of [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you get to the point of writing code, then SO is the right place to ask about any specific problems that you have with the code.

Comment: ok, thanks, Maybe I put some code in the question when I have something near to work.